# How can I translate a Haskell code segment to a mathematical representation?

Tags: computer-science, programming

I am trying to translate some Haskell code to a mathematical notation.
Below is a Haskell program that represents a stack of physical blocks.

```
-- set of blocks
data Block = B1  | B2 | B3  | B4 | B5 | B6 | B7 | B8   deriving (Eq,Show) 
-- MoveOnto(bl,b2,t) is read as b2 is moved into and onto bl on table t.
data Stack = EmptyTable  |  MoveOnto Block Block Stack deriving Show 
isOn :: Block -> Block -> Stack -> Bool
isOn b1 b2 (MoveOnto b3 b4 s) |  ((b1 == b3) && (b4 == b2)) || 
                                  (isOn b1 b3 s)  || 
                                  (isOn b4 b2 s) =  True                        
isOn _ _ _  = False                             

testTransitivityTrue = 
    isOn B1 B4 (MoveOnto B1 B2 (MoveOnto B2 B3 (MoveOnto B3 B4 EmptyTable)))
testTransitivityFalse = 
      isOn B3 B1 (MoveOnto B1 B2 (MoveOnto B2 B3 EmptyTable))
```

Blocks can only be placed on a table or another block using constructors `EmptyTable` and `MoveOnto`. The Boolean function `isOn` is a decision procedure for deciding whether a given block is on top of another.

Here is my attempt at a mathematical representation:
$$Blocks = \{ B_1 \ldots B_{10} \}$$
$$Stack = \{ EmptyTable \} \cup $$
$$\{ MoveOnto(B_1,B_2,EmptyTable), MoveOnto(B_2,B_1,EmptyTable),\ldots \} \cup$$
$$\{ MoveOnto(B_3,B_2,(MoveOnto(B_2,B_1,EmptyTable))), \ldots \}$$
The two sets above, $Blocks$ and $Stack$, consist of all possible constructed terms for the block world algebra. I did not include the detailed subscripts. The following is my attempt at representing the Boolean Function `isOn`.
$$
isOn(b_1,b_2,MoveOnto(b_3,b_4,s)) =
 \begin{cases}
true, &  \text{if } (b_1 = b_3) \land (b_4 = b_2) \\
true, &  \text{if } isOn(b_1,b_3,s) \\
true, &  \text{if } isOn(b_4,b_2,s) \\
false,    &  \text{if }  isOn(b_1,b_2,EmptyTable) 
   \end{cases}\\
$$

I don't think that I can use Haskell's `otherwise` clause for the false case. I use wildcard or *don't care pattern* instead of explicit variables. I believe that this due to pattern matching, where `EmptyTable` cannot match `MoveOnto(b3,b4,s)`.  I am not sure of how this could be represented mathematically. Can `otherwise` be used in the the math?  Both the terms $EmptyTable$ and $MoveOnto(b_3,b_4,s)$ are in the set $Stack$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people use "otherwise" in case notation, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline), and it is a bit cleaner:

$$
\operatorname{isOn}(b_1,b_2,\mathtt{MoveOnto}(b_3,b_4,s)) =
 \begin{cases}
\mathtt{true} &  \text{if } (b_1 = b_3) \land (b_4 = b_2) \\
\mathtt{true} &  \text{if } \operatorname{isOn}(b_1,b_3,s) \\
\mathtt{true} &  \text{if } \operatorname{isOn}(b_4,b_2,s) \\
\mathtt{false} &  \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}\\
$$

While not necessary, it is useful to keep the variables, operators and constants distinct. There is a difference between $$\sin\alpha$$ and $$sin \alpha,$$ and for the same reason I've used `\mathtt` for `MoveOnto` constructor and constants `true` and `false`; there are also symbols $\top$ and $\bot$, but I find these less readable.

Regarding the sets, you might want to prefer
\begin{align}
B &= \{\mathtt{B}_1, \ldots, \mathtt{B}_{10}\}, \\
S_0 &= \{\mathtt{EmptyStack}\}, \\
S_k &= \{\mathtt{MoveOnto}(b_1, b_2, s) \mid b_1, b_2 \in B, s \in S_{k-1}\}, \\
S &= \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} S_k. \\
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful answer. What is the distinction between $\sin\alpha$ and $sin \alpha$?

Comment: @PatrickBrowne $\sin \alpha$ is the value of sine at $\alpha$ while $sin\alpha = s \cdot i \cdot n \cdot \alpha$.